# Trouble using Sprytile

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on

After creating a flat 'landscape' surface using textures in [Sprytile](https://chemikhazi.itch.io/sprytile) I find that, after selecting some of the surfaces and pushing and pulling them, when they move some are not connected to neighbouring tiles.

Why is this?